# Error when PyPDFOCR calls ImageMagick for multiple page PDF

Tags: python, pdf, imagemagick

[updated]

I have PyPDFOCR installed on Windows along with Tesseract, ImageMagick, and Poppler.

In Python, the PDF files do convert, but I get a warning -

```
WARNING: Could not execute identify to calculate DIP (try installing imagemagic?), so defaulting to 300dpi
```

I do have imagemagick 7.07 installed in C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16 and my run-time Python path adds this to the path:

```
 os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + 'C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16'
```

The application `identify` is in C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16.

By changing line 146 in [pypdfocr_gs.py](https://github.com/virantha/pypdfocr/blob/master/pypdfocr/pypdfocr_gs.py#L146) to read
`cmd = 'magick identify -format "%%w %%x %%h %%y" "%s"' % pdf_filename`

non-null `results` (lines 149-150 in pypdfocr_gs.py) are returned.

However, if more than one page is in `C:\myfile.pdf`, the script fails on line 151:

```
 width, xdensity, height, ydensity = [float(x) for x in results.split()]
```

because it's expecting a tuple of 4 to unpack, but it's 4x however many pages there are.

Comment: Is PyPDFOCR compatible with ImageMagick 7. Perhaps you need ImageMagick 6. In ImageMagick 6, you can call `identify`. But in ImageMagick 7, it would be `magick identify`. So my guess is your PyPDFOCR need ImageMagick 6 not 7.

Comment: Try updating [pypdfocr_gs.py](https://github.com/virantha/pypdfocr/blob/master/pypdfocr/pypdfocr_gs.py#L146) to use `magick identify` as the command.

Comment: I changed `identify` to `magick identify` in pypdfocr_gs.py line 146, but it stil hits  the exception 'Could not execute identify'.  I also reverted the above line, uninstalled imagemagic 7.07 and installed 6.99 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/imagemagick and get the same issue.

Comment: Line 148, `out = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)` returns nothing.  When I run `identify -format c:\myfile.pdf` from `cmd`,  it seems to execute but returns nothing.

Comment: OK, by monkeying around with it, I found that `cmd = 'identify -format "%%w %%x %%h %%y\n" "%s"' % pdf_filename` creates the warning but by removing the newline: `cmd = 'identify -format "%%w %%x %%h %%y" "%s"' % pdf_filename` it processes as expected.